# Azure Event Hubs - REST API Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have a Python program that generates streaming data. Each piece of data is stored as a variable called `message`.

Since Event Hubs does not offer a Python SDK, I've opted to use [their REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/send-event). I've attempted to push the data to my Event Hub instance as a part of my Python program that generates data as follows:

```
r = requests.post("https://{Instance name}.servicebus.windows.net/{Path}/messages", message)

print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

Upon executing this code, I receive a `401 Unauthorized` response.

After running into this issue, I used [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/69823/creating-shared-access-signature-sas-for-posting-d.html) tutorial to try and create a shared access signature. Upon using `curl` to confirm that my generated token worked, I received a `HTTP/1.1 401 40103: Invalid authorization token signature` response.

Is there a better way to send the data while still generating it in Python? A better way to create a shared access signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure SDK for Python supports sending messages to Event Hubs: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/azure-servicebus#event-hub.

I'd suggest using the SDK but if you really want to call the REST API directly, take a look at the Event Hubs methods implementation in the SDK source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-servicebus/azure/servicebus/servicebusservice.py.

Comment: I didn't realize the Azure SDK had Event Hubs support. I'm up and running because of your help. Thanks!

Comment: links from above are broken -> 404