# Event Hub API POST: 40103: Invalid authorization token signature

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub, sas-token

Before this gets marked as a duplicate: I have read every question/answer on SO with the above error message, and none of them solved my problem. I must be missing something simple, as what should be simple is not working.

I have created an Event Hub Namespace, with a "Send" Shared Access Policy and an Event Hub in the namespace.

Using the code from the [Python Event Hub SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/azure/eventhub/client.py#L55) (which was [suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44273541)), I have the following script to create my `Authorization` header:

```py
import time
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from hashlib import sha256
from hmac import HMAC
from urllib.parse import quote_plus, urlencode

def generate_sas_token(uri, policy, policy_key, expiry_days=14):
    expiry = time.time() + expiry_days * 60 * 60 * 24
    encoded_uri = quote_plus(uri)
    ttl = int(expiry)
    sign_key = '{}\n{}'.format(encoded_uri, ttl)
    signature = b64encode(HMAC(b64decode(policy_key), sign_key.encode('utf-8'), sha256).digest())
    result = {
        'sr': uri,
        'sig': signature,
        'se': str(ttl),
        'skn': policy
    }
    return 'SharedAccessSignature ' + urlencode(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NAMESPACE = input('Namespace: ').strip().lower()
    URI = '{}.servicebus.windows.net'.format(NAMESPACE)
    POLICY = input('Policy: ').strip()
    POLICY_KEY = input('Policy key: ').strip()
    EXPIRY_DAYS = int(input('Expiry (days): ').strip())
    print(generate_sas_token(URI, POLICY, POLICY_KEY, EXPIRY_DAYS))
```

Now, if I run this script using the following (dummy) values:

```
NAMESPACE=<my Event Hub Namespace> # let's call it "ehns"
POLICY=<"Send" Shared Access Policy Name> # let's call it "event-publisher"
POLICY_KEY=<Primary Key for the above policy, ends with = sign>
EXPIRY_DAYS=14
```

then I get the following (dummy) `Authorization` header:

```
SharedAccessSignature sr=ehns.servicebus.windows.net&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%3D&se=1574773874&skn=event-publisher
```

Now when I POST a dummy message to the API endpoint, [following this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/send-event):

```sh
curl -i -X POST --data-ascii "test message" -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -H "Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=ehns.servicebus.windows.net&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%3D&se=1574773874&skn=event-publisher" https://ehns.servicebus.windows.net/ehresource/messages
```

I get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 SubCode=40103: Invalid authorization token signature
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2019 13:11:34 GMT
```

Notes:

- I have also tried generating the Shared Access Signature with the shell commands on [this page](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Creating-Shared-Access-Signature-SAS-token-for-Azure-Event/ta-p/248244), linked to by one of the questions/answers, to no avail.
- I have also tried the [Event Hubs Signature Generator](https://github.com/sandrinodimattia/RedDog/releases/tag/0.2.0.1), with no more success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use the code below:

```
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
from urllib.parse import quote_plus, urlencode

def _sign_string(uri, key, key_name):

    '''
    100000 = milsecond expiry
    '''
    expiry = int(time.time() + 10000)

    string_to_sign = quote_plus(uri) + '\n' + str(expiry)

    key = key.encode('utf-8')
    string_to_sign = string_to_sign.encode('utf-8')
    signed_hmac_sha256 = hmac.HMAC(key, string_to_sign, hashlib.sha256)
    signature = signed_hmac_sha256.digest()
    signature = base64.b64encode(signature)

    return 'SharedAccessSignature sr=' + quote_plus(uri)  + '&sig=' + quote_plus(signature) + '&se=' + str(expiry) + '&skn=' + key_name


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    URI = "your_eventhub_namespace.servicebus.windows.net/your_eventhub_name"
    POLICY = "your_policy_name"
    POLICY_KEY = "the policy key"

    print(_sign_string(URI,POLICY_KEY,POLICY))
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: There are only two differences between your script and mine. ___ 1. You encode the key with utf-8, while I decode it from base64. ___ 2. You `quote_plus` the URI and signature in the SharedAccessSignature, while I only `quote` the signature (the URI is the same). ___ I thought that I had tried encoding the key with utf-8, and I thought there was no difference between the quoted versions, but yours magically works.

Comment: I can confirm that this script works like a charm!